# Better approach for this slide-out side panel?

Tags: jquery, width, slide

I made this slide-out side panel from scratch: http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/ts3s3yx4/4/

I didn't use a pre-built script because I'm trying to improve my raw coding skills. My approach is a bit unpredictable and glitchy... the red panel sometimes flickers on the wrapped line below when you click OPEN and I feel like there could be a totally different, simpler approach to this whole concept?

```
$(function() {
    $("#open").click(function() {
        openPanel();
    });

    $("#close").click(function() {
        closePanel();
    });
});

function openPanel() {

    $(".left-box").animate({
        width: "65%"
    }, 100);
    $(".panel").animate({
        width: "25%"
    }, 100)

}

function closePanel() {
    $(".panel").css("width", "0");
    $(".left-box").animate({
        width: "90%"
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: position of .panel absolute? or fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Looks okay... here's a simple edit to get the flicker to stop, and simplify the click handlers:

```
$(function() {
    $("#open").click(openPanel);
    $("#close").click(closePanel);
});

function openPanel() {
    $(".left-box").css('margin-right', '0%').animate({
        width: "65%"
    }, 100);
    $(".panel").animate({
        width: "25%"
    }, 100)
}

function closePanel() {
    $(".panel").css("width", "0");
    $(".left-box").animate({
        width: "90%"
    }, 100, function(){$(".left-box").css('margin-right', '')});
}
```

[**See this update**](http://jsfiddle.net/oftaf7j3/3/)

Comment: That does work... but I don't want a 5% to the right of the panel. And the button-wrap div drops down for a split second when you click open before the panel snaps back up to the same line. I can obviously address these issues with brute-force approaches (absolute position on the buttons, display none on the panel until open, etc.) but those feel like duct tape solutions. I mean, I LOVE duct tape but... :) http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/ts3s3yx4/5/

Comment: @KirkRoss per your comment, I updated the fiddle link and code--you need to remove the `margin right` on the left box when opening and remove it when closing :)  Oh and you can also animate the panel closing now, instead of just setting it to 0 width...

Comment: So if we don't add back the margin-right after animation, then isn't that the same as just removing it from the CSS so it's never there to begin with? Ultimately I wanted a margin-between the two boxes and thought everything added up to 100% it shouldn't flicker. My concept was to have the left box fill up the whole window with 5% margins... 5-90-5... and then shrink so the panel comes into view. 90 -25 = 65.